# Why Images Does not displayed using php

Tags: php, apache2

I did the php code for displaying the images that available in the folder. When I am run the code the image can't be displayed whereas the image holding place to be taken by the browser. Hereby I have mentioned my code kindly any one help what mistake I did. Thanks. If it is possible to share php code for displaying the images that available in the folder?

```php
 $files = glob("/home/aspire/Downloads/*");
 for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
 {
     $num = $files[$i];
     echo $num."<br>";
     echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="Here should be image" width="256" height="192" >'."                <br>"."<br>";
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is this script located?
You should prepend variable $num in `echo '<img src="'.$num.'"` with relative path to the image file.

If your PHP Script is located in /home/aspire the displaying code will look like this:
`echo '<img src="Downloads/'.$num.'"` ...`

Comment: Mickula I have added what you have told but the still the can't be loaded but the space to be taken

Comment: in what folder is your script located then?

Comment: /home/aspire/Downloads/ with this directory I have images.I am configured the apache dirctory path in "/home/aspire/public_html/" in folder also I have save the above programming php file. Is this make a trouble load image ah ?

Comment: yeah, probably images are not accessible from webserver point of view. move your Downloads to /home/aspire/public_html and change script as I mentioned in answer

Comment: Your answer for put the images in the Public_html folder also I was change the glob("/home/aspire/Downloads/"."*.*"); to glob("/home/aspire/Images/"."*.*"); based on Rab Nawaz code. That's why the reason for I am accept his code.

Answer (score 2):

use `glob` as

```
glob("/home/aspire/Downloads/"."*.jpg");
```

OR

```
glob("/home/aspire/Downloads/"."*.*");
```

**and make sure that the path is correct**

Comment: Oh thanks correct that mistake but still the image can't loaded but it takes space kindly help me..